# Odoo 11 cannot load my custom modules

Tags: odoo-11

I have installed odoo 11 with yenthe script. Added the custom addons folder path to odoo config file under etc. Restarted the odoo server. Clicked on update apps list but I cannot view my custom modules in apps list. I think odoo cannot find my addons folder. Permissions are also allowed for that directory to odoo user. No errors appear on log file. Kindly help.

----My Config File---------------------------------

```
[options]
; this is the password that allows database operation:
admin_passwd=****
db_port=5432
db_user=user_name
xmlrpc_port=8069
logfile=/var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
addons_path=/odoo/enterprise/addons,/odoo/odoo-server/addons,/odoo/custom/addons
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when forgot to add **manifest**.py, check your file structure. Are you using Filezilla to transfer the files?

If you want you can also share your module so I could try it on a clean install